# Open mobile first console is not wworking

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am developing an app with ibm mobilefirst v7.1 . It was working fine until today morning an update for windows 10 .after that am facing the problem **Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found ** when i try to do **open mobile first console** on my application nothing opens and also when i direclty put server url i get the above error msg and the important point is when i check the server console i get the below **note:i have deleted mobilefirstserver folder,cleaned workspace,restarted still same occur**`help pls and thanks in advance.

```
Application 'k' with all environments build finished.
[2015-12-31 12:55:59]             Deploying application 'k' with all environments to MobileFirst Server... 
[2015-12-31 12:56:45]             Application 'k' deployed successfully with all environments
Web application available (default_host): http://192.168.*.*:10080/_MobileBrowserSimulator/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application _MobileBrowserSimulator started in 1.788 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0016I: Starting server configuration update.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0017I: The server configuration was successfully updated in 2.473 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://192.168.*.*:10080/j/
[WARNING ] Using empty value for configuration property 'wl.analytics.logs.packages'
```

Comment: What about re-installing Studio?

Comment: any other possibilities than reinstalling??

Comment: Try to delete the wlresources folders from the tmp folder in Windows.

Comment: You ought to be giving more details:
a) An app ? Are you developing a Windows 8 / Universal application? Or a hybrid - Android/Windows8/ Windows Phone Silverlight application?
b) Did the error start right after the Windows 10 update?
c) when i check the server console i get the below - get what?
d) i have deleted mobilefirstserver folder,cleaned workspace,restarted still same occur - what exactly did you delete?
e) Stand alone server or do you see the error with MobileFirst studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Locate your [temp folder](http://www.askvg.com/where-does-windows-store-temporary-files-and-how-to-change-temp-folder-location/)
3. Delete the `wlBuildResources` folder
4. Open Eclipse
5. Re-build